# AngularJS Dependency injection in controller of routeProvider resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

Injecting the return object of a `resolve` which should be injected into the controller, but it's not. I am using a promise so that the controller does not instanciate until the promise is resolved, since I am doing a HTTP POST using the `$http` service.

I am also doing some redirection depending on the response data by using `$location.path`. The first route will redirect to the `template1` route with the data it has obtained.

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/auth/:id", amd.route(
    {   
        controller: 'eventController',
        controllerUrl: 'app/controllers/eventController',
        resolve: {
            returnedData: ['$http', '$location', '$route', '$q', function ($http, $location, $route, $q) {
                var id = $route.current.params.id;
                var defer = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://domain/service/webapi',
                    data: { 'name': id }
                }).then(function (response) {
                    var template = "/template".concat(response.data.displayLayout);
                    defer.resolve(response.data);
                    $location.path(template);
                    return defer.promise;
                });
            }]
        }
    }))
    .when("/template1", amd.route(
    {
        templateUrl: 'views/templates/template1.html',
        controller: 'eventController',
        controllerUrl: 'app/controllers/eventController',
    }));

app.controller('eventController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$timeout', 'returnedData',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $timeout, returnedData) {
        // ...controller code here: $scope.returnedData = returnedData
});
```

I am getting the AngularJS error:

> Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the AngularJS API page, about the routeProvider (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

you can see:

> resolve - {Object.=} ... If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated

You should edit your code like below:

```
var id = $route.current.params.id;
var defer = $q.defer();
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://domain/service/webapi',
    data: { 'name': id }
}).then(function (response) {
    var template = "/template".concat(response.data.displayLayout);
    defer.resolve(response.data);
    $location.path(template);
});
// return the promise outside `then` method, then angularjs will wait it `resolve`
return defer.promise;
```

---

And further more, Please notice this:

> Be aware that ngRoute.$routeParams will still refer to the previous route within these resolve functions. Use $route.current.params to access the new route parameters, instead.

Comment: Great!! Now the `returnData` object is being injected in my controller when the `$location.path(template)` line is commented-out. Problem now is how do I pass a resolve result from one path to the next in the $routeProvider ?

Comment: If the data you resolve is complex: 
You can use `Service` to do it. Because `Service` is a unique in a module, so it can be use to trans data easily.Define a Service and inject in both two path.
if it's very simple:
You can directly use $routeParams and put the data in the path next.
Wish could help you

Comment: It worked! I created a service directly in the module used for routing and since services are singletons in Angular, I can reuse it later to fetch the data from it.

Comment: Very happy for your success ~

Answer (score -2):

Using Dependency Injection with ng-route , 
my solution:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "localytics.directives"]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "//TimeLine.html",
            controller: "MainCtrl"
        })    
        .when("/AddOrEditOccasion", {
            templateUrl: "/Html/GiftWhiz/AddOrEditOccasion.html",
            controller: "AddOrEditOccasionCtrl"
        })
        .when("/OccasionStart", {
            templateUrl: "/OccasionStart.html",
            controller: "OccasionStartCtrl"
        })        
}]);


myApp.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

   //your codes

}]);
```

Comment: please explain what does this code do and where to put it. As currently written, this is hardly an answer.. Best regards